# Setting up Reverse DNS - SERVFAIL error

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, nslookup

I am using Ubuntu Server and installed BIND9 so I could set up a DNS server. I am tying to configure Reverse DNS.
Here is my `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file:

```
zone "grupolar.com" in{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.grupolar.com";
};

zone "0.13.10.in-addr.arpa" in{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.10.13.0.rev";
};
```

And here is my `/etc/bind/db.10.3.0.rev` file:

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN 0.13.10.in-addr.arpa.
@    IN    SOA    ns1.grupolar.com.    adm.grupolar.com.    (
                  10000                ; Serial
                  604800               ; Refresh
                  2419200              ; Expire
                  604800 )             ; Negative Cache TTL
     IN    NS     ns1.grupolar.com.
11   IN    PTR    server1.grupolar.com.; qualified name
12   IN    PTR    server2.grupolar.com.
```

The command `nslookup 10.13.0.11 - 10.13.0.10` is producing the following:

```
Server:    10.13.0.10
Address:   10.13.0.10#53

** server can't find 11.0.13.10.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL
```

This is for academic purposes and I would like to know what I am doing wrong, if you could help me.

When I use `named-checkzone 0.13.10.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/db.10.13.0.rev` command, I get the following output:

```
dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/db.10.13.0.rev:7: near eol: unexpected end of input
zone 0.13.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/db.10.13.0.rev failed: unexpected end of input
zone 0.13.10.in-addr.arpa/iN: not loaded due to erros.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/db.10.13.0.rev:7: near eol: unexpected end of input`

The error message which is included in the question says that there is an error on line 7 in the zone file.  This position coincides with the end of your `SOA` record.

The problem is that your `SOA` record is missing one of its seven fields.

A `SOA` record has the following fields `MNAME`, `RNAME`, `SERIAL`, `REFRESH`, `RETRY`, `EXPIRE` and `MINIMUM` (in this order).

One of the five integer fields is missing in your `SOA` record, based on your comments it is the `RETRY` field which is missing.

Comment: The named-checkzone command returned OK now, but the nslookup command is still giving me the same error. Do you have any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: Have you made bind reload the zone after fixing this? `rndc reload` or similar.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I always use `sudo service bind9 restart` but this one time I forgot. Thank you for your time :)